# Scrapy JSON get value

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

Using this [link](https://www.shutterstock.com/sstk/api/footage/images/search?site=image&image_type=vector&q=&page%5Bnumber%5D=1&studio=1&include=contributor-limited-meta) I am trying to get the following data after every instance of this which would be 100 data sets

```
contributor-limited-meta":{"data":{"id":"4103089"
```

The expected result would be:

> 768919,
>   4103089,
>   193246966,
>   976367,
>   508762,
>   and more

I have tried `response.xpath('//script').re(r'author":"([0-9.]+?)"')` via the `scrapy shell` but I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

You could use requests then use json from response and extract in a loop

```
import requests
res = requests.get('https://www.shutterstock.com/sstk/api/footage/images/search?site=image&image_type=vector&q=&page%5Bnumber%5D=1&studio=1&include=contributor-limited-meta').json()
results  = []
for item in res['data']:
    id = item['relationships']['contributor-limited-meta']['data']['id']
    results.append(id)
print(results)
```

With scrapy use json

```
jsonres = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode()
```